# Enter username under a label class

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I am automating a web page. I can enter text on other web pages. For the following code, I am not able to enter username and password:

Username:

```
<label class="required" for="id_password">Password:</label> <input type="password" name="password" required id="id_password">
<input type="hidden" name="next" value="/books_fbv_user/">
```

Below is the code in python:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
username = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='id_userame']")))
username.send_keys("user")
```

Comment: `I am not able to enter username and password` why not? do you get an error? can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: Hi Chris,                                                                                                                   There is no error. The cursor is placed in the username textbox, it blinks
I am not sure if send_keys is working                                                                                      Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following and its working.

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='id_username']").click()
time.sleep(2)
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='id_username']").send_keys('anon')
```

Thanks